# starting a process from a .NET windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I am trying to start a console application from a .NET Windows Service. The service is running  on a Windows 2008 server.

I use Process.Start to run the console application and it runs( I can see it in the task mgr), but I never get the process id back and the call to Process.Start just hangs.
If I run the same service from my Windows 7 machine the process runs and I get the process Id back no problem.

I am confused ..

Comment: Did you set UseShellExecute to false?  Are you redirecting its output?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly this same problem. For me the key was to set StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the process you are spawning is attempting to prompt the window station for user input? In which case it could hang...

Which process are you starting? Is it part of the platform/OS (like cmd.exe) or something custom?

Comment: it is a custom process that starts listening on a specific tcp port. It does listen but I cannot get the process id back to the windows service that started it.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time search for a solution for this, I found the wise stones for my problem.

I made a new WindowsForm based program, with same Process.Start command, and then the standard "Windows Warning Security" dialog box shows up, and thats why it dosent work.

After turn off "User Access Control" the Windows Service works correctly.