# Build Webpage For Remote Management of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, remote-control

I would like to build a mini web app type page on my local machine where I can run CMD commands.

For example, my ideal set up would be over the Internet I can go to WANIP:1111, get prompted for user/pass and then be presented with a page where I can do things like reboot the machine and so on using commands such as `shutdown.exe -r`.

I'm basically looking for the functionality of the Web Interface option of the [Shutter program by den4b](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=shutter) but I'd like to build it and customize it myself. I'm also assuming that I wouldn't have to run an additional program to do it the way I described.

**How would I go about creating this?**
Do I need a certain server? Certain technology?

Comment: OK - what have you done so far?

Comment: @Diodeus Well, the original question was asking what I would need to do to set this up from scratch. IE: I would have to set up a webserver on my local machine, forwards some ports, open some firewalls and so on. I'm not sure what to do. So far I've tried setting up an IIS server but I can't access it from outside http://serverfault.com/questions/438979/access-iis-site-one-windows-7-home-premium-over-the-internet but can't seem to make it work. I'm familiar with PHP more so than .NET is it possible to do with PHP?

Comment: @Diodeus Any help and suggestions to make the question better would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790071/starting-a-process-from-a-net-windows-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short PHP solution:

1. [Install Apache and PHP](http://drupal.org/node/264)
2. [Secure it with htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)
3. [Use exec to run commands](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

[Here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/825380-shutting-down-pc-using-php) is  discussion about how to shutdown a pc using php with working code. And [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/120621/how-to-change-port-number-of-apache-server-in-windows-os) are instructions to change the port apache listens to.

That should be all information you need to install the server and build a php script with the desired functionality.